# Why "convert" from ImageMagick makes an empty blank PNG image on some machines?

Tags: ubuntu, svg, imagemagick

I'm doing this, in order to convert `a.svg` to `a.png`:

```
$ convert -verbose -density 300 -quality 100 -colorspace RGB a.svg a.png
'inkscape' '/tmp/magick-IzF5R-f12XvI7X-ColE5CglRNjuNMCrr' --export-filename='/tmp/magick--fW_TQpKspQREgCh_JyXTXv2RxaOzSe4.png' --export-dpi='300' --export-background='rgb(100%,100%,100%)' --export-background-opacity='0.99999999999900002212' > '/tmp/magick-VwBlgvqIBVn1FHewJTz4M92i32xg38RA' 2>&1
mvg:/tmp/magick-36-3BbMBCBFnYGZ_ErYqD-XBUzUAlJ6j=>/tmp/magick-36-3BbMBCBFnYGZ_ErYqD-XBUzUAlJ6j MVG 1687x1775 1687x1775+0+0 16-bit sRGB 192732B 0.120u 0:00.089
a.svg SVG 1687x1775 1687x1775+0+0 16-bit sRGB 192732B 0.000u 0:00.001
a.svg=>a.png SVG 1687x1775 1687x1775+0+0 8-bit RGB 1c 1710B 0.480u 0:00.137
```

The file I'm getting is a blank PNG (totally white, nothing inside). However, on other machines (macOS and Ubuntu), the generated image is correct. On GitHub Actions Ubuntu 22.04 I'm getting the blank one.

This is what I'm getting on *all* machines:

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have Inkscape on all the computers? Do you have IM 6.9.11-60 on all the computers?

Comment: Show the verbose command/results on the good machine as well as the bad one.  Show the IM version on both machines. Are you sure you are getting the same IM version and delegates on both machines? Do you have the same versions of libpng on both machines?  Do you have Inkscape on both machines and the same versions?  Note that IM can use any one of 3 SVG renderers: Inkscape, RSVG delegate or the internal IM MSVG renderer, in order of decreasing capability.  So there may be features in your SVG file that only Inkspace can process properly.  **POST your SVG file!**

Comment: Indeed, the absence of `inkscape` caused the problem. This is what solved it: `apt install inkscape`. @fmw42 please, turn this into an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Inkscape on both machines and the same versions? Note that Imagemagick can use any one of 3 SVG renderers: Inkscape, RSVG delegate or the internal IM MSVG renderer, in order of decreasing capability. So there may be features in your SVG file that only Inkscape can process properly. So be sure you have installed Inkscape on each system and try again.